# Сломался JS поле обновления JQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

У меня на сайте была старая версия JQuery подключена и на главной 2 скрипта работали хорошо.

В связи с обновлением CMS(Wordpress) обновилась и версия JQuery, после этого на главной странице(остальные я даже боюсь смотреть пока что) перестали работать скрипты "Топ новости" и "А также..".

Топ новости у меня получилось реанимировать и теперь они работают хорошо, а вот скрипт "А также..." никак не получается реанимировать.
Очень прошу помочь исправить ошибку, чтобы всё работало.
Код скрипта:

```
function New(){
            $.get("http://zapraudu.info/wp-content/themes/govory/also.php",{page:parseInt($("#pagenavi span.current").text())-1,lang:""},function(data){$('section.and').html(data);});
            return false;
}  
function Old(){
            $.get("http://zapraudu.info/wp-content/themes/govory/also.php",{page:parseInt($("#pagenavi span.current").text())+1,lang:""},function(data){$('section.and').html(data);});
            return false;
}
```

Ошибка которая появляется при просмотре дебагером:

> > uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Собственно сайт, на котором можно посмотреть как оно работает [zapraudu.info](http://zapraudu.info)

Comment: Переменная `$` не определена. Попробуйте в начале скрипта написать напрямую

    var $ = jQuery;

Comment: а скрипт с jQuery точно подгружается?

Comment: А если так

    function New($) {...
    function Old($) {...

Comment: Сделал так, как вы написали. 
Теперь, при загрузке страницы этот скрипт отрабатывается(автоматически, а должен по клику)
При клике на "Предыдущие новости" происходит ошибка 
uncaught referenceerror: old is not defined
такие же при клике на "Следующие новости"

Comment: @cema93, самый простой вариант - вернуть все как было и заменить $ на jQuery.

Comment: Вернул всё как было, заменил $ на jQuery
При нажатии на "Предыдущие новости" появляется ошибка uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function

Comment: значит ваш скрипт грузится до jQuery.

Comment: Я сделал как вы написали, к сожалению ничего не изменилось, всё так же, хотя, как я понял, вы мне другую ошибку исправили :)

Comment: @cema93 я не вижу больше ошибки в консоли.

Comment: Попробуйте нажать "Предыдущие новости", новости должны смениться, но этого не происходит, а только появляется ошибка:

uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще все ваши проблемы от того что у вас используется "onclick" в разметке, поэтому приходится засорять глобальную область видимости да еще и функция одна называется New(), что вообще не хорошо

вот такую магию попробуйте.

```
var New,Old;
(function($) {
New=function(){
                $.get("http://zapraudu.info/wp-content/themes/govory/also.php",{page:parseInt($("#pagenavi span.current").text())-1,lang:""},function(data){$('section.and').html(data);});
                return false;
        }
Old=function(){
                $.get("http://zapraudu.info/wp-content/themes/govory/also.php",{page:parseInt($("#pagenavi span.current").text())+1,lang:""},function(data){$('section.and').html(data);});
                return false;
        }
})(jQuery);
```

---

по хорошему надо делать так:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('section.and').on('click','.old,.new',NewOld);
  function NewOld(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var direction=$(this).hasClass('old')?1:-1;
    $.get("http://zapraudu.info/wp-content/themes/govory/also.php",{page:parseInt($("#pagenavi span.current").text())+direction,lang:""},function(data){$('section.and').html(data);});
    }
});
```

и убрать onclick из разметки.

Comment: сделал как вы написали, сработало 1 раз, но больше не реагирует(

Comment: поправил и немного изменил логику.

Comment: Обновил код на сайте, ничего не поменялось

Comment: извините, перепутал +direction

Comment: вообще у вас никакого индикатора загрузки нет :( очень неудобно и не понятно когда оно грузится

Comment: Спасибо, обновленный код работает, хоть и есть касяки небольшие, если много кликать.
код сайта, который вы помогали мне исправить, был написан в 2011 году.
Сейчас частично переписывавю код сайта, как могу...
Если есть предложения по улучшению кода, то буду рад их услышать тут или в скайпе